# Connecting to postgres from windows to virtual machine

Tags: postgresql

I have the following setup

- Windows 8
- Oracle VM virtual box with arch Linux running on it
- Installed and configured PostgreSQL on Linux
- Setup the ports in virtual box so that

  - 45432 port on windows goes to 5432 on Linux
  - 40022 port on windows goes to 22 on Linux
- On Linux PostgreSQL, I have created user `erjik` and database `mydb`.
- Firewall is shut down on windows.

The problem is that I am trying to connect from `intellij` idea using JDBC PostgreSQL  driver, just trying test connection to address:

```
jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:45432/mydb

username: erjik
password: xx
```

However, the test connection fails.

`pg_hba.conf` goes unchanged after installation with following settings:

```
local all all trust
// IPv4
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
// IPv6
host all all ::1/128 trust
```

In postgresql.conf I have set only this settings:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

and

```
port = 5432
```

What could be the reason of connection attempt fail? Maybe I missed some settings.

EDIT1: 
on Linux side the command:

```
psql -h localhost -U erjik mydb
```

executes successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you connect to the PostgreSQL instance via the forwarded port in the VM you're not really connecting to localhost, the port is being forwarded to the actual IP of the virtual network interface. You need to modify `pg_hba.con` to allow connections from IP addresses other than `127.0.0.1` for this to work.

To open up to everything add the following to `pg_hba.conf`. You can optionally  restrict the address to your local machine's IP address (or a subset of it):

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

Once it's updated restart the server or send the master process a `SIGHUP` so it reloads the `pg_hba.conf` file.

---

FYI, you can verify that this is what happening by creating a "server" using [nc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) and trying to connect to it from your local machine.

On the VM forward the port 12345 to your local machine and try the following. Note that the *"Connection from ..."* output will come after you do the next step. See how it's not `127.0.0.1`:

```
your-pgvm$ nc -v -l 12345
Connection from 10.0.2.2 port 12345 accepted
```

On your Windows machine:

```
your-comp$ nc localhost 12345
```